# ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT is not fired when intializing the store

Tags: redux, ngrx

I have an effect with an Init Effect =>

```
  @Effect()
  init$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT),
    map(action =>
      new featureActions.GetAllMissionRequest({
        projectID: environment.projectId,
        projectContextID: environment.projectId
      })
    )
  );
```

I added this at the bottom of the file, I also tried to include a defer, but this effect is never triggered when my store are initialized.

I checked on the repo of ngrx, but the solution I applied to not trigger my function.

am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

For this case you can implement on your effect OnInitEffects :

**yourAction.ts**

```js
export const initEffect = createAction('[ModuleToto] init effect');
```

**yourEffect.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class YourEffect implements OnInitEffects {
  ngrxOnInitEffects(): Action {
    return initEffect();
  }

  init$ = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(initEffect),
      map(action =>
        new featureActions.GetAllMissionRequest({
          projectID: environment.projectId,
          projectContextID: environment.projectId
        })
      )
    )
  );

}
```

I saw this on https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#oniniteffects

Answer (score 1):

In order for the event to dispatch you have to register your effects:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.forRoot([MovieEffects])
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#registering-root-effects

Comment: I have a slightly different implementation, at the moment I have this ; ```missionEffect``` is imported in my missionModule 
    ```EffectsModule.forFeature([MissionsEffect])```
which is importent in the ```RootStoreModule```
but not inside the 
```imports: [MissionsModule,    EffectsModule.forRoot([])]```
should I change the import ```forFeature``` to import ```forRoot``` ? or just remove the RootStore     ```EffectsModule.forRoot([])```

Comment: so Basically 
 ```MissionEffect ``` => imported in  ```MissionModule ``` with    ```StoreModule.forFeature('missions', missionReducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([MissionsEffect])```

and 

 ```MissionModule ``` => imported in  ```RootStoreModule ``` with ```imports:[MissionsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([])]```

Comment: To elaborate on this answer:

Feature effects, ie. ```EffectsModule.forFeature(MyEffect)```, are setup after ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT fires.

To use ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT, your effect must be registered in root using ```EffectsModule.forRoot(MyEffect)``` in a non-lazy-loaded module. See:


https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/683

Consider creating your own init action, firing when module has loaded.

@timdeschryver, sorry to see https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1305 was reverted - will it get another go some day?